# How to improve performance of the query joining on string basis?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, performance, join

I have two table

1. `order` Table
2. `marketplace_payment` Table

An `order` table contain a field `marketplace_ref_no` Having Type `varchar(24)` Collation `utf_general_ci`

A `marketplace_payment` Table contains this field with same name `marketplace_ref_no` Having Type `varchar(24)` Collation `utf_general_ci`

However When I am trying to join both the tables, It is taking 2 minutes 48 second to execute. What are the measures should i take?

Comment: Are the fields indexed?

Comment: No I have not used any indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider indexing the columns. This will have the effect of reducing the number of rows that must be searched. Read more here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html